# Folium error "Expecting value"

Tags: python, leaflet, data-science, folium

```
map.choropleth(geo_path=countries, data=to_plot,
           columns=['CountryCode', 'Value'],
            key_on='feature.id',
            fill_color='YlGnBu', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=.5)
```

I am getting the error below, and the code is copied verbatim (except for the exclusion of legend title) from a source that works, so I'm at a loss

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a code problem; it's a data problem. What are the values of `countries` and `to_plot`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I think you're right. The JSON file pointing to countries doesn't have any country codes or anything that looks like geometries to me.

Comment: HI, what is type and value of `countries`?   And could you update your question with a sample of the json?